# What is the difference between a Solana Slot and Block?

Tags: block-time

When I use solana block explorers such as solana.fm they sometimes refer by block and sometimes slot.

Is there a concise explanation you can provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slot is a fixed amount of time currently set to 400ms within which a validator has the opportunity to produce a block.

A block on Solana contains a set of transactions with metadata such as the previous blockhash, timestamp e.t.c

Big shoutout to the Helius blog which is where I got this information too.
Here is the article https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-slots-blocks-and-epochs